# Multiple Reference To Same External Table in Yii

Tags: php, yii, relational-database

I'm quite new to Yii development and I find myself stuck at the very beginning..

In my project I have a table with two columns both pointing to an external table.
Something like:

```
table "item":
- user_id_1
- user_id_2

table "user":
- id
```

So an item i always associated with two users, but I do not want to differentiate them, and I want to be able to do something like

```
$item->users
```

getting both the users.
And also the opposite:

```
$user->items
```

getting all items that reference the user id in user_id_1 or user_id_2.

Does this sound right? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yii's ActiveRecord is really only set up to handle one-to-one and one-to-many relationships - you seem to be describing a one-to-two relationship.

One way to handle this would be to set up a [MANY_MANY relationship](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship), but just use it with two users instead of "many". You will need to set up a `user_item` table that connects Users to Items, instead of embedding the key directly in the tables. If you need to enforce *only* two Users-to-an-Item you'll need to write some extra Validation code in your Item model. The relation in Item will look something like this, and you will be able to call `$item->users` like you want:

```
public function relations() {
  return CMap::mergeArray(parent::relations(),array(
    'users'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'User', 'user_item(item_id,user_id)'),
  ));
}
```

The new associative table will look like this:

```
user_item:
-- user_id
-- item_id
```

If you really need to use two separate user_id foreign key fields like you have here, you will need to set up an ActiveRecord HAS_ONE relation for each, like so:

```
public function relations() {
  return CMap::mergeArray(parent::relations(),array(
    'user1' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id_1'),
    'user2' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id_2'),
  ));
}
```

*But*, you can still enable the `$item->users` call syntax with a function something like this, which will return both users in a single array:

```
public function getUsers() {
  return array(
    $this->user1,
    $this->user2,
  );
}
```

This takes advantage of Yii's `__get()` method override, which will allow you to call `$item->getUsers()` like `$item->users`.

You can set up something similar in the User model, with two HAS_MANY relations for `user_id_1` and `user_id_2`, and a `getItems` method which returns the merged result arrays.

But I think the easiest option will be to set up a MANY_MANY relationship (and use it a ONE_TWO relation).